# Why do the results of the Equals and ReferenceEquals methods differ even though variables are reference types?

Tags: c#, object, reference, equals

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn documentation

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the **Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method**.

then why does following code results in two different result of method calls `Equals` method returning **True** and `ReferenceEquals` method returning false, even though the `obj` and `obj1` is reference type as `IsClass` property returns true.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new { a = 1, b = 1 };
        var obj1 = new { a = 1, b = 1 };
        
        Console.WriteLine("obj.IsClass: " + obj.GetType().IsClass);
        
        Console.WriteLine("object.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj1): " + object.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj1));
        
        Console.WriteLine("obj.Equals(obj1): " + obj.Equals(obj1));
    }
}
```

Output:

> obj.IsClass: True
>
> object.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj1): **False**
>
> obj.Equals(obj1): **True**

Comment: Anonymous types override Equals and GetHashCode

Comment: Read more of that page you've linked to - "Because the Object class is the base class for all types in the .NET Framework, the Object.Equals(Object) method provides the default equality comparison for all other types. However, types often override the Equals method to implement value equality".

Comment: i missed the point that anonymous objects override equal method.  @JenishRabadiya btw it was obvious for my self xD so i forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`obj` and `obj1` refer to 2 different objects, so `object.ReferenceEquals()` will return false.

`Equals()` returns true, because the compiler implements `Equals()` for anonymous types. It will return true if all the properties of both objects have the same values.

Comment: Thanks! will accept answer in next couple of minute. :)

Answer (score 3):

All anonymous types have an `Equals` override that works by:

1. If the first object is null then return `true` if the second is null, `false` otherwise.
2. If the second object is null, then return `false`.
3. If the two objects are of different types, return `false` (but all anonymous objects who have the same properties which are the same name for the same type in the same object are the same type).
4. Go through each of the properties, if calling `Equals` on the values the two objects have for that property is `false`, return `false`.
5. Return true.

(They also have a `GetHashCode` which works by combining `GetHashCode` calls on each property).

If it wasn't for this, then `GroupBy`, `Distinct`, `Union` and similar couldn't work with anonymous properties, since each of those methods needs a concept of equality to work.

`ReferenceEquals` works by returning `true` if the two objects are in fact the same object, `false` if they are not.

The default for a non-anonymous object is for `Equals` to return the same thing as `ReferenceEquals`. If it was not anonymous, and something other than this was desired then the author would have provided an `Equals` override, and would have much greater flexibility in how they did so.